# How to adjust width of histogram columns in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using a heatmap to draw a figure in ggplot2 for different datasets. The problem is: everytime I draw a heatmap, the column width varies and thus the graphs look inconsistent next to one another.[image]

As you can see here, the width of the colored columns is different.

This is the code I am using:

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Codon,y=ID,fill=state))
q <- p + geom_raster()
```

And this is sample data:

```
structure(list(ID = c("281154_491", "281154_491", "281154_491", 
"281154_491", "281154_491", "281154_491"), Codon = c(18L, 28L, 
79L, 81L, 84L, 86L), state = c("possible_adapted", "nonadapted", 
"nonadapted", "nonadapted", "nonadapted", "nonadapted")), .Names = 
c("ID", "Codon", "state"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data? My guess is that you should try specifying `scale_x_continuous` and settings `breaks` and `labels` the same for each chart.

Comment: Thanks @Mako212 I added in a sample of the data. I tried adding 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,100,200,300))    but that changed the x-axis labeling only and didn't adjust the scale / width of each bar.

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/4421870) for guidelines on how to create a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use the `coord_fixed()` and specifying the same ratio for all your plots:

```
> p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Codon,y=ID,fill=state))
> q <- p + geom_raster() + coord_fixed(ratio = 20)
```